# JUnit: timeout некорректно работает?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, timeout

Есть следующий тест:

```
@Test(timeout = 15)
public void test() throws Exception {
    AesCrypt aes = new AesCrypt("password");

    String crypted = aes.encrypt("Test string");
    Assert.assertEquals("Test string", aes.decrypt(crypted));
}
```

По идее, он  должен проваливаться, если время выполнения превысит 15ms. В тоже время, как видно на скриншоте, тест выполнялся 23ms, но всё равно считается пройденным.

Из-за чего так?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: А что вы хотите протестировать? Попробуйте запустить тест вне IDE.

Comment: @Mikhail время выполнения. Или я неправильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Обычно в юнит-тестах таймаут служит для предотвращения зависания тестов. Производительность юнит-тестами не проверяют. В чем цель данного теста?

Comment: @Mikhail одна из целей - как раз замерять производительность. Но почему для этого нельзя использовать JUnit?

Comment: JUnit - это не benchmark фреймворк. Использовать JUnit в этом качестве нельзя. Хотите измерять производительность возьмите, например [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: @Mikhail так а всё же, почему нельзя? Ведь раз в JUnit есть такой параметр, почему бы им не воспользоватся в этих целях(что, кстати говоря,вполне ожидаемо)?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: @Mikhail вопрос остаётся тот же - почему параметр `timeout` некорректно работает с малыми величинами.

Comment: вы запустили тест вне IDE?

Comment: @Mikhail нет, тест был запущен в IDE.

Comment: пожалуйста, запустите тест вне IDE.

Comment: @Evgeniy IDE всегда будет разное время показывать. на это влияют множество факторов. помимо метода внутри теста, пинаются еще волкеры и инвокеры. они тоже занимают время, но ты это не видишь.

Comment: бенчмаркать время выполнения нельзя по той простой причине, что на другой машине с другой загрузкой время выполнения будет непредсказуемым. да и на той же самой тоже!

Comment: более того, с чего вы взяли, что 23 мс прошли внутри теста, а не между двумя событиями, отловленными IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование `@Test(timeout = 15)` не является потокобезопасным, использование может привести к неправильным результатом. Используйте следующий код.

```
public class Test {
    @Rule
    public Timeout globalTimeout= new Timeout(9);

    @org.junit.Test()
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(8);
    }

    @org.junit.Test()
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

}
```

вывод

```
org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 9 milliseconds

at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at Test.test2(Test.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Такой подход позволяет отловить даже 1 миллисекунду.

Также в `jUnit5` можно использовать

```
    assertTimeoutPreemptively(ofSeconds(15), () -> {
        // This method takes 20 seconds to run
        myMethod();
    } , () -> "myMethod() method took more than 15 seconds and was aborted.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Запустите тест вне IDE и перед запуском теста выполните очистку (clean).

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, описать как это сделать?

Comment: что именно описать? какую систему сборки вы используете? maven? gradle?

Comment: Как запустить тест вне IDE и как сделать очистку. Сборщик никакой не использую.

Comment: А какую IDE используете? И какой тип проекта выбрали?

Comment: IntelIiJ IDEA, проект Kotlin(Java)

Comment: Kotlin нужен принципиально? Или простая java подойдет?